# Cocoa: most lightweight way to synchronize access to a double?

Tags: c, cocoa, thread-safety

In my Cocoa/iOS application I have a static `double` variable (let's call it `foo`) which must be:

1. updated by one part of my app on a background thread
2. read by another part of my app on the main thread

I'm looking for the most lightweight way to synchronize access to `foo`.

***Note**: I know that the simplest solution in these cases is usually to adjust the code such that only one thread accesses the variable, and therefore no synchronization is necessary. Let's assume that I have determined that restricting `foo` access to a single thread is not possible in this case (maybe the action taken in step **1** occurs so rapidly/often that thread switching is not desirable). Please do not respond with an answer of "restrict `foo` access to one thread". I am looking for alternatives to that.*

---

My current understanding is that using a `volatile` variable is the most lightweight way to synchronize access to `foo`. So `foo` is declared something like this:

```
static volatile double foo = 60.0;
```

Background thread writing code is something like:

```
foo = 90.0;
```

Main thread reading code is something like:

```
double bar = 0.0;
bar = foo;
// use bar here …
```

---

Some questions:

1. Is the main thread guaranteed to see the updated value of `foo` after it is written on the background thread (given that `foo` is declared `volatile`)? IOW, Have I done enough to ensure that the two threads will see the result each other's read/write operations?
2. I'm assuming that using `volatile` for a `double` value is faster/more-lightweight/preferable in this situation rather than a mutex lock like an `@synchronized` block or an `NSLock`. Is that true? IOW, is `volatile` the best solution for  this particular case?

Comment: volatile doesn't guarantee atomicity.

Comment: @mkb ...especially when the think marked as volatile is larger than a machine word, which may be the case here.

Comment: @mkb awesome. good info. if that's true then I don't think volatile will work in this case.

Comment: @JesseRusak : is atomicity guaranteed for a volatile variable which is machine-word-size?

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf: no, the volatile keyword doesn't prevent thread Y from writing to the same location after thread X has read from that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **No**. `volatile` is not a substitute for an atomic primitive here. Close, but not quite.

2) Problem with `volatile` is, it's not *correct*, as you now know.

Ideal: You may have access to the latest atomic language features, such as `_Atomic` for C11 and/or `<atomic>` in C++11.

If not, then you could either use a 64 bit integer and atomic functions, which you read by value, then transfer to a `double`, or you could use a simple `pthread_mutex_t` or perhaps even a spin lock (be very careful with spin locks).

However… it may be better if you simply post changes to the value to the main thread's run loop, if that is an option.

Comment: thx @Justin. I am beginning to think there will not be an alternative to exclusive thread access which would be better for me in this particular case.

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf yeah, it really depends on what you are doing -- there are some corner cases where messaging the main thread of changes is just not an option (realtime/nolock). the problem with not notifying is that you often end up spinning or polling for changes. so, i'd probably just narrow it down to builtin atomics, or OSAtomic read->moves using OSAtomic.h functions if that is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Cocoa has built-in primitives for this. Check out the contents of [OSAtomic.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW14)

You could use `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier` to write (correctly aligned and volatile) doubles in an atomic fashion. You probably also need a `OSMemoryBarrier` before reading to ensure you see latest value as well. I believe that this will only work on 64-bit architectures, since 32-bit architectures will probably not read the 64-bit double in an atomic fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I would use GCD for this, creating a concurrent dispatch queue that manages access to the variable. Readers can simply

```
__block double bar;
dispatch_async(foo_queue, ^{ bar = foo; });
```

and the write can use a dispatch barrier:

```
dispatch_barrier_async(foo_queue, ^{ foo = someOtherFoo; });
```

The call to `dispatch_barrier_async` ensures that any pending reader blocks are executed completely, then the write block will be executed and the value updated before any more reader blocks can execute.

This is a pattern recommended by Apple in some of the GCD videos from WWDC.

Comment: This is awesome. I had not seen this yet. Very glad to learn of it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

GCC has [atomic primitives](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) which might be what you need. I have no idea how well these are supported when building for iOS, and it probably changes depending on whether you use `gcc`, `llvm-gcc`, or `clang`.